# Rails accept_nested_attributes still throws "Can't mass-assign protected attributes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested-attributes

I think I'm either missing something really simple or something really obscure. Hoping someone can spot it for me or explain my muppetry.

Ok, So there are two models, Basket and BasketItem.

I've set Basket to accept_nested_attributes :basket_items with the intention of using fields_for in an edit view of Basket.

However when run up it still screams that

```
Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: basket_items_attributes
```

For the sake of this question I've boiled down to the same issue if I do a manual basket.update_attributes in the console with just one or two basket_item attributes. So I know it's a model issue, not a view or controller issue.
e.g.:

```
basket.update_attributes("basket_items_attributes"=>[{"qty"=>"1", "id"=>"29"}, {"qty"=>"7", "id"=>"30"}])
```

or similarly with a hash more like fields_for makes

```
basket.update_attributes( "basket_items_attributes"=>{
"0"=>{"qty"=>"1", "id"=>"29"}, 
"1"=>{"qty"=>"7", "id"=>"30"}
})
```

I've ensured that the associates in defined before the accepts_nested_attibutes_for, that the child model has the appropriate attributes accesable too, tried removing additional attributes for the nested data, lots of fiddling to no avail.

basket.rb

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basket_items
  attr_accessible :user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :basket_items
  belongs_to :user



  def total
    total = 0
    basket_items.each do |line_item|
      total += line_item.total
    end
    return total
  end

  # Add new Variant or increment existing Item with new Quantity
  def add_variant(variant_id = nil, qty = 0)

    variant = Variant.find(variant_id)

    # Find if already listed
    basket_item = basket_items.find(:first,  :conditions => {:variant_id => variant.id})

    if (basket_item.nil?) then
      basket_item = basket_items.new(:variant => variant, :qty => qty)
    else
      basket_item.qty += qty
    end

    basket_item.save

  end

end
```

basket_item.rb

```
class BasketItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :basket
  belongs_to :variant

  attr_accessible :id, :qty, :variant, :basket_id

  def price
    variant.price
  end

  def sku
    return variant.sku
  end

  def description
    variant.short_description
  end

  def total
    price * qty
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you just need to add `basket_items_attributes` to your list of accepted attributes.

So you'd have

```
attr_accessible :user_id, :basket_items_attributes
```

at the top of your basket.rb file

Comment: Thank you. This resolved it. Could have sworn I'd tried this as a solution, but must have been jumbled with other flailing solutions which confused it.